# APEX 4.2.1 max concurent users on GlassFish

Tags: oracle, glassfish, oracle-apex

Let's say I have an Oracle recommended 2GB of RAM available on my Solaris server and it is a pure webserver, database is elsewhere (same intranet, low latency).

Assuming my backend database is powerful enough that GlassFish is the bottleneck - how many concurrent users can I support with a default install of GlassFish listener?

Does anyone have the numbers of concurrent users sessions that their installs can sustain?

I ask because we are familiar with how much load our databases can sustain so are only interested in the new component - the APEX listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glassfish Max Thread Pool Size defaults to 5.
APEX Listener MaxLimit defaults to 10.

So in this setup the real concurrent sessions is just 5. But as a user will probably be idle most of the time (reading what's on the screen etc), you can serve a lot more users with just 5 sessions. How much ... depends on your application (and how fast your users press the submit button).

You can use some load testing tool like jMeter to see how many users your configuration can handle,